# How to update javaFX table with data reveived in another thread via Ethernet

Tags: java, javafx

I want to know how to update a JavaFX table with data received via network in a socketDataReceiver thread every 1 second and put that data in a HashMap. As and when data is put into HashMap(gets updated periodically), I want javaFX table to get updated with City_Id, Latitude, Longitude information. Here is the sample code

**GPSLocation.java**

```
public class GPSLocation {

    public Short cityId;
    public Double lat;
    public Double lon;

    public GPSLocation(short cityId, double lat, double lon) {
        this.cityId = cityId;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
    }
}
```

**CityCentreLocation .java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CityCentreLocation extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TableView tableView = new TableView();


        TableColumn<Short, GPSLocation> column1 = new TableColumn<>("City_Id");
        column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("cityId"));

        TableColumn<Double, GPSLocation> column2 = new TableColumn<>("Latitude");
        column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lat"));


        TableColumn<Double, GPSLocation> column3 = new TableColumn<>("Longitude");
        column3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lon"));


        tableView.getColumns().add(column1);
        tableView.getColumns().add(column2);
        tableView.getColumns().add(column3);

        VBox vbox = new VBox(tableView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

**ReceiverThread.java**

```
Map<Short, GPSLocation> cityLocations = new HashMap<Short, GPSLocation>();

...
//Received socket data is present in buff of length 18

objGPSLocation.cityId = ByteBuffer.wrap(buff, 0, 2).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getShort();    
objGPSLocation.lat = ByteBuffer.wrap(buff, 2, 8).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getDouble();
objGPSLocation.lon = ByteBuffer.wrap(buff, 10, 8).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getDouble();

cityLocations .put(objGPSLocation.cityId, objGPSLocation); 

...
```

Now I want to populate this map data in javaFX table.

Comment: what's the problem, exactly?

Comment: @Kleopatra How to show the HashMap collection data in javaFX table

Comment: The type parameters for your `TableColumn`s should be the other way round. The first one is the `TableView` item type, the second one the type displayed in cells of this column. Your compiler would have told you, if you didn't use the raw type for `TableView`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single correct answer for your task at hand.

The easiest, quick and dirty way, would be to get the items from the table, pass a reference of this `ObservableList` to your receiver thread. When your receiver thread receives an item, you can just add it to the list. But you'll have to do this in the JavaFX platform thread.

In your Application class:

```
ObservableList<GPSLocation> items = tableView.getItems();
ReceiverThread receiver = new ReceiverThread(items);
receiver.start()
...
```

In your Receiver - assuming you have an instance variable `items`:

```
GPSLocation location = ...;
Platform.runLater(() -> items.add(location));
```

That should basically do the trick.

It's not very clean, though. Your receiver should not know UI-related stuff, like `ObservableList` and `Platform`. Your receiver should actually push new locations to some kind of interface or queue. It's just to get you started.